# Is this a good technique (Using data holder) to eliminate anonymous class, to reduce memory leak risk

Tags: java, android

Anonymous class can easily cause memory leak, especially in Android world, where Activity or Fragment can suddenly destroyed due to configuration changes. Here are one of many examples.

http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=696

http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/10/12/anonymous-inner-classes-in-android/

https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/memory_leaks_made_easy

The reason is that, creating an anonymous class in `Activity` or `Fragment`, the anonymous class will always hold an implicit reference to the `Activity` or `Fragment`. So, when `Activity` tends to go out of life due to configuration changes, it cannot be garbage collected if the anonymous class is being exposed and hold by outside world.

**So, I was wondering, whether using a data holder technique is a good way, to completely eliminate anonymous class, to reduce risk of memory leakage? Or, am I over paranoid?**

### Using anonymous class

```
public class HomeMenuFragment {
    private Parcelable selectedInfo = null;
    private List<View> homeMenuRows = new ArrayList<View>();

    private void fun() {
        ...
        ...
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // homeMenuRows is member variable
                for (View r : homeMenuRows) {
                    r.setSelected(false);
                }
                row.setSelected(true);
                // selectedInfo is member variable
                selectedInfo = watchlistInfo;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Refactor using data holder technique

```
public class HomeMenuFragment {
    private static class Holder {
        public Parcelable selectedInfo = null;
        public final List<View> homeMenuRows = new ArrayList<View>();        
    }
    private final Holder holder = new Holder();

    private static class MyOnClickLisnter implements OnClickListener {
        private final Holder holder;
        private final LinearLayout row;
        private final WatchlistInfo watchlistInfo;

        public MyOnClickLisnter(Holder holder, LinearLayout row, WatchlistInfo watchlistInfo) {
            this.holder = holder;
            this.row = row;
            this.watchlistInfo = watchlistInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            for (View r : holder.homeMenuRows) {
                r.setSelected(false);
            }
            row.setSelected(true);
            holder.selectedInfo = watchlistInfo;
        }        
    }

    private void fun() {
        ...
        ...
        row.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickLisnter(holder, row, watchlistInfo));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your point but is the OnClickListener really going to be passed around to the outside world?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for [http://codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You may ensure OnClickListener or OnClickListener's holder (which is row) doesn't expose to outside world during your code modification. But future maintainer may expose them accidentally. No one know. The best for us as developer is, to reduce such risk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactoring like this does not help. The `View` objects in the `Holder` also hold references to the `Activity`, so if the `Holder` is exposed to the outside world you have a memory leak. Also, your `MyOnClickLisnter` instance, even though it is declared `static`, is holding an explicit reference to the `Holder` and a `LinearLayout`, both of which are holding references to the `Activity`. I'm not a fan of anonymous classes, but I think the chances of an anonymous `OnClickListener` being passed outside of the `Activity` or `Fragment` are very very small. Sounds to me like you are being overly paranoid.